# Best approach between Using and public object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know what is the best approach between using statement and creating a public variable.
My example is the following:
I have a manager class which inherits from disposable, and this class has access to my dbcontext and methods to it.
What I am doing now is on my cs class doing a ussing to that class and create and destroy my object to my needs.
For example:

```
public class StudentManager:  IDisposable
{
    private ISchoolUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public StudentManager()
    {
        _unitOfWork = new SchoolUnitOfWork();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
}
```

On my cs class I do:

```
private IEnumerable<Stundets> GetStudents()
{
    using (StudentManager manager = new StudentManager())
    {
         return = manager.GetStudents();
    }
}
```

OR

```
private StudentManager = new Studentmanager();
```

What is the best way to do it: having the instance of my StudentManager (just create a connection and destroy when leave page) or working with the `using`?

I am a bit confused about that. Thanks in advance!

I do update my context on the same manager calling the save at my context which is an interface of my unit of work, I do not access directly to the context, but when I construct it I construct one type my unit of work.

I do save on my crud operations on the manager. So on my manager on update, insert, modify I call the save method, for example:

```
public class StudentManager....

        public Student UpdateStudent(Student student)
        {
            IStudentService service = new StudentService(_unitOfWork.StudentRepository);
            Student student= service.Update(student);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return student;
        }
```

In general, I have an Interface IUnitOfWork and a UnitOfWork, also have a IRepository and a repository. And I just use a manager to not instantiate my UnitOfWork directly, but with a manager to it... I think that's legal and useful!

Comment: Side note, your business classes should not own the repositories and should not need IDisposable. But that only shifts your problem with the connection.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with keeping the context in a private field and disposing it within the Dispose() method of the class that constructs it, IMO. Using blocks are a shortcut to the try/catch/finally pattern that ensures that disposable objects are disposed when you are done with them - but this is only *one pattern* for ensuring that objects are disposed in a timely fashion. Existence of this shortcut does not automatically render all other patterns unusable.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is the `using` statement because it calls `Dispose` automatically. You can guarantee that your disposal logic will occur. This is, in fact, how you should use objects like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` as well. So you're doing it right with the `using`.

In fact, you stated that you're using a `DbContext` to access the data. Those should be **instantiated on demand** and wrapped in a `using` as well. There is no need to **share** an instance of these types of classes because connection pooling is done **at the SQL Server** via the connection string.

Comment: But that could lead to creating multiple copies.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, much like you would create a new `SqlConnection` every single time you want to use it.

Comment: No, not the same. Connections are pooled. Contexts would lose their change tracked cache every time.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, that would matter if you had a lapse between updates to the objects and pushing them to the database I guess, but if you were updating the objects and then pushing them to the database immediately that wouldn't be true right?

Comment: It's a bad idea to always wrap an EF `DbContext` in a using statement, _especially_ in the context of a `UnitOfWork` pattern. If you query your context, add things and dispose of your context every time, it won't do anything useful.

Comment: @SimonBelanger, when you say it won't do anything useful, what **exactly** does that mean?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Let's say your repository wrap every request in a using statement. A service class use that repository to query a user by ID change some properties and then save the changes. Since your context is disposed, nothing will happen. The whole repository should keep it's context until its disposed. Not create a new context for every method.

Comment: I use the unitofwork pattern, but on my pages I could use more than one manager, I think is a litle ugly to have a global variable for every manager I has to use... what about performance, is better to just have one variable or more and use it or, create when I need it and destroy it? What about the pooling? Thanks!

Comment: I can save it, because on my crud operations I do save. For example:

Comment: @SimonBelanger, if that's true then I would recommend staying away from `DbContext` as a whole. I'll need to test this on my own. But in short, leaving that instance alive and sharing across multiple threads even, is quite simply a recipe for disaster. If what you're saying is true then the `DbContext` itself does nothing useful.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud `DbContext` is useful as it acts as a `UnitOfWork` pattern itself. It's meant to be used, as the name implies, in a _context_. A view is a context, a user control (in WPF for example) is a context, and so on. In a user control, you would keep your `DbContext` alive in the `UserControl` life span and dispose it at the same time. If used correctly, it's extremely useful. But it should definitely not be used statically and across threads.

Comment: @SimonBelanger, maybe I'm thinking more in respect to the application I write I guess. There is no way that class would be useful with 20K+ consumers of the same service. So maybe it's just not useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use using then might be in a single you need to write similar stuffs more than once. For example

```
//To get all students
private IEnumerable<Stundets> GetStudents()
{
using (StudentManager manager = new StudentManager())
{
    return = manager.GetStudents();
}
}

//To save Students
//To get all students
private IEnumerable<Stundets> SaveStudents()
{
using (StudentManager manager = new StudentManager())
{
    return = manager.Save();
}
}
```

and so on. But here you dont have to worry about the disposing of the object. It will be taken care automatically. If you go for global declaration , you need to do it manually. So what i need to say, If you have to use the StudentManager all over the page why dont you make it global and use it all over the required places, using both.Something like this

```
private StudentManager manager;

//To get all students
private IEnumerable<Stundets> GetStudents()
{
using (manager = new StudentManager())
{
    return = manager.GetStudents();
}
}

//To save Students
//To get all students
private IEnumerable<Stundets> SaveStudents()
{
using (manager = new StudentManager())
{
    return = manager.Save();
}
}
```

Comment: If I do this when I do a ussing it will destroy automatically close, right? I just use a manager to dont load the cs class and just call my dbcontext when I need it...